# What purpose does this serve? IIFE assignment to var in Snap.svg.js

Tags: javascript, snap.svg, iife

My self-directed javascript study has finally led me to reading libraries where I found the following snippet (truncated for brevity). I'm using Firefox with firebug on a windows apache server (xampp).

I figured the snippet below would suffice but if anyone needs it, the entire library can be found here: [snap.svg.js on github](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/tree/master/dist)

```js
var Snap = (function(root) {
Snap.version = "0.4.0";

function Snap(w, h) {              // can be either width, height OR 
 if (w) {
  if (w.nodeType) {                        // deterimines if parameter is a dom element
   return wrap(w);
  }
  if (is(w, "array") && Snap.set) {        // deterimines if parameter is an array
   return Snap.set.apply(Snap, w);
  }
  if (w instanceof Element) {              // deterimines if parameter is a Snap.Element
   return w;
  }
  if (h == null) {                         // by elimination determines if parameter is a dom element id.
   w = glob.doc.querySelector(String(w));
   return wrap(w);
  }
 }

<numerous public and private properties and methods> 
.
.
.
glob.win.Snap = Snap;
return Snap;
}(window || this));
```

Firebug shows the Snap object in the window context before instantiating any user objects. I was wondering exactly what mechanism was injecting the Snap object into the DOM.  That's when I noticed the "var Snap".  Initially, I thought that was it.  But, since it didn't break the app when I changed the variable name or even deleted it, I became confused.

Further investigation resulted in the discovery at the bottom of the iife... specifically, "glob.win.Snap = Snap".  Since "window" is being passed into the iife, it seems this is what's actually creating the Snap object in the window.  Changing the name to glob.win.Snappy confirmed this.

I'm still learning so please correct me if I'm wrong.  I'm trying to understand what's going on with this library.  It seems that the function Snap() is being injected to the window context via the glob.win.Snap assignment.  I don't see that the "var Snap" at the top or the "return Snap" are doing anything.  In fact, I can rem them out and everything seems to function fine.  So, my first question: Do those two lines serve some function I'm not seeing?

A secondary question is: What does the "this" fallback parameter refer to?  My limited understanding of Snap is that it is always used within the window namespace so wouldn't "this" always be the window?

Just when I think I'm beginning to make the paradigm shift from classical to prototypical language, I run across code like this and it sets me back.  I'd really appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the referenced source code, here a more condensed version:

```
var Snap = (function(root) {
    Snap.version = "0.4.0";

    function Snap(w, h) {}

    var glob = {
        win: root.window,
        doc: root.window.document
    };

    ...

    glob.win.Snap = Snap;
    return Snap;
}(window || this));

Snap.plugin(...);
```

> It seems that the function Snap() is being injected to the window
>   context via the glob.win.Snap assignment. I don't see that the "var
>   Snap" at the top or the "return Snap" are doing anything.

You are correct, the declaration of `var Snap = ...;` and assignment via `return Snap;` is superfluous, since that variable lives in the global scope (i. e. the Window object) and is already declared by `glob.win.Snap = Snap;`

I assume they just keept that var declaration since it is pretty much standard when using the class pattern:

```
var MyClass = (function() {
    function MyClass(n) {}
    return MyClass;
})();
```

> A secondary question is: What does the "this" fallback parameter refer
>   to? My limited understanding of Snap is that it is always used within
>   the window namespace so wouldn't "this" always be the window?

In some JavaScript environments, the root object is not called `window` (e.g. `global` in node.js). `window || this` will evaluate to the root object, no matter what it is called.

You will see such dependency injections often in JavaScript modules. See https://carldanley.com/js-module-pattern/ for more.

However, it seems that this library will not run if there is no `window` object available due to the `var glob = { win: root.window, ... }` assignment. They might just have kept the `this` in there because it is part of a standard module pattern.